# Simple condition to refresh page and try find_element again when not found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Pretty basic question. I have no knowledge in python and tried to get a basic selenium tool running which does the following:

Opens a webpage and clicks a certain element/link if available. If the element is not present/availiable, refresh the page and try again until the element is clickable again and again until it succeeds.

Background: I need to join a course as fast as possible, which is available on a specific date/time.

What I got so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


driver.get("URL")
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join")
link.click()
```

It successfully clicks the link when the element is found, if not it will produce the `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:` Error, sure because it didn't find the requested element.

How to get the script to repeat `find.element` in loop and refresh the page until the element is showing up on the specific date/time.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer that you have would never come out of `infinite loop.` Also it does not refresh in case Element was not found.

**Code :**

```
while True :
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Join")) > 0:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join").click()
            print("successfully clicked on Join link")
            break
        else:
            driver.refresh()  # refresh the web page. 
            time.sleep(5)  # 5 sec break. 
    except:
       print('Something went wrong')
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use "try" and "except" in Python to handle the exception without quiting

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

while True:
    try:
        driver.get("URL")
        link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join")
        link.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Element Not Found")
    sleep(0.5)
```

Here is more information about exception in Python:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Hope it would be helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much, so it refreshes with a 0.5 sleep until it is able to find and click the element?

Comment: @Johannesv.R. It will refresh and click again even it has clicked the element. You may need to add 'break' under 'link.click()'. 0.5 second sleep will avoid 100% CPU usage (serious system lag). You can decrease this value but remember, the website could block you if you request too frequently.

Comment: Okay, thanks. One more thing: If the join was successful, there will be a message displayed that is was successful, is it possible to implement this message to stop the loop of clicking?

Comment: @Johannesv.R. As I said, the simplest way to do that is add 'break' under 'link.click()'. After click is executed successfully, 'break' means jump out the loop.